# Change to force Windows 11 RDP login to use Authenticator app

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, login, two-factor-authentication

I want to login to my Windows 11 server using RDP, but I want to force the login to use Microsoft Authenticator app, my account is not a school or work, it is a personal account.

Comment: I assume you are talking about a RDP server you connect to using the "Microsoft Terminal Services Client" aka "Remote Desktop Connection" `mstsc.exe` which is included in Windows (not the Microsoft Remote Desktop app).

Comment: Unclear: Do you want your phone to be used to unlock your computer when you're away from the computer?

Comment: @harrymc Based of the combination of "Authenticator app" + two-factor-auth tag my guess this question is more about Windows login with additional TOTP code.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all comments, I received an answer from Microsoft community that Windows 11 does not support Auth App, which is what I was looking for, so I need to find another solution for remote access.

Thanks you everyone